# How to install gcc-4.3 in ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-11.10

I want to install gcc-4.3 but it's not installed in Ubuntu 11.10. How can I do that in Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: have you tried google `install gcc4.3 ubuntu11`?

Comment: GCC 4.3 is very old. Just install the latest `gcc` compiler (probably 4.5 or 4.6) of your distribution with `aptitude install gcc g++`  and use it. There is no reason to install an old version of GCC if you can use a newer one. FYI GCC 4.7 has just been released on http://gcc.gnu.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to compile and install your own version of GCC on Ubuntu, you will first need to make sure the GMP, MPFR, and MPC libraries are installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3c2 libmpfr4 libmpc2
```

You may have to add the directory with the MPC libraries to your path in `bash`:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/lib
```

Then after downloading and untarring the GCC tarball, create a build directory in the GCC directory, and in that new directory issue

```
../configure --prefix=/path/to/where/you/install --program-suffix=-4.3.X
```

This will configure an installation of your own GCC in its own directory with the suffix '-4.3.X' (where 'X' matches the version you are installing) to distinguish it from any other installation of GCC.  Then you can `make [install]` as usual, and hopefully no errors come up.  The last step is to make sure the path to the new GCC installation is in your `$PATH`.